# Write Data to SQL DW from Apache Spark in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse

When I write data to SQL DW in Azure from Databricks I use the following code:

```
example1.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw").option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall).option("dbtable", "SampleTable12").option("forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True") .option("tempdir", tempDir).mode("overwrite").save()
```

This won't work with with Notebook in Synapse Notebook. I get the error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o174.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.sqldw. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:656) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource
```

Basically, I need to know the equivalent of `com.databricks.spark.sqldw` for Apache Spark in  Azure Synapse.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing to a dedicated SQL pool within the same Synapse workspace as your notebook, then it's as simple as calling the `synapsesql` method.  A simple parameterised example in Scala, using the parameter cell feature of Synapse notebooks.

```
// Read the table
val df = spark.read.synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.${pSchemaName}.${pTableName}")

// do some processing ...

// Write it back with _processed suffixed to the table name
df.write.synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.${pSchemaName}.${pTableName}_processed", Constants.INTERNAL)
```

If you are trying to write from your notebook to a different dedicated SQL pool, or old Azure SQL Data Warehouse then it's a bit different but there some great examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export).

UPDATE: The items in curly brackets with the dollar-sign (eg `${pDatabaseName}`) are parameters.  You can designate a parameter cell in your notebook so parameters can be passed in externally eg from Azure Data Factory (ADF) or Synapse Pipelines using the Execute Notebook activity, and reused in the notebook, as per my example above.  Find out more about Synapse Notebook parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks?tabs=classical#designate-a-parameters-cell).

[image: Synapse Notebook parameters]

Comment: thanks for sticking with me on this.
I added the following, but I'm getting the error 'incomplete statement'
```%%spark
val pDatabaseName = "MyFirstSQLPool"
val pSchemaName = "dbo"
val pTableName = "mysampletable3"
val df.write.synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.${pSchemaName}.${pTableName}_processed", Constants.INTERNAL)```

Comment: The way I’d do it is have two cells, Cell 1 have the three parameters and make sure that cell is designated a parameter cell.  You can do this by clicking in the top right-hand corner of the cell.  Then have Cell 2 which uses those parameters.  Make sense?

Comment: Also, where’s the element in your code which is populating the dataframe (df) ?

Comment: Morning @wBob. I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The code that is populating df is test = spark.sql("select * from testtable")

Comment: I have changed the code to populate the dataframe to:
```%%spark
val scala_df = spark.sqlContext.sql ("select * from stgProbateGrantCaseAll")

scala_df.write.synapsesql("sqlpool.dbo.PySparkTable", Constants.INTERNAL)```

Comment: I'm now getting the error
```Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for struct<caseType:string,applicationType:string,boDocumentsUploaded:array<string>,applicationSubmittedDate:string,declaration:struct<:string,accept:string,confirm:string,confirmItem1:string,confirmItem2:string,confirmItem3:string,requests:string```

Comment: your original solution worked like a dream. The problem was that the SQL Dedicated Pool was paused .. doh!

Comment: oh, just one last thing, can you let me know how to add the option to 'overwrite' tables in  the database please.

Comment: You can't currently as far as I'm aware.  That's why in my example I pass the table back with a `_processed` suffix and let Synapse Pipelines handle the swap afterwards with a Stored Procedure activity.

Comment: That's not ideal. With Databricks you can do an update or an overwrite ... not good. Thanks though