# Spark errors when writing to Synapse DWH pool

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database, databricks, azure-synapse

I am trying to write a dataframe in either append/overwrite mode into a Synapse table using ("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") connector .The official docs doesn't mention much about ACID properties of this write operation. My question is that , if the write operation fails in the middle of the write, would the actions preformed previously be rolled back?

One thing that the docs does mention is that there are two classes of exception that could be thrown during this operation: SqlDWConnectorException and SqlDWSideException .My logic is that if the write operation is ACID compliant,then we do not do anything,but if not,then we plan to encapsulate this operation in a try-catch block and look for other options(maybe retry,or timeout).

Comment: Are you using a Synapse notebook?  If so, why not use the built-in connector as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export#write-api-1) and some more notes from me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67908817/1527504).

Comment: @wBob My bad I didn't mention the notebook. Well its Azure Databricks. Then again, does that connector guarantee ACID?

Comment: Can you share the exact error you see ?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MTI haven't got any error till now, what we are looking at is->how do we handle the situation if an error is thrown unexpectedly ,once the code is moved from DEV to PROD. We are thinking of implementing a try-catch mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good practice you should write your code to be re-runnable, eg delete potentially duplicate records.  Imagine you are re-running a file for a failed day or someone want to reprocess a certain period.  However SQL pools does implement ACID through transaction isolation levels:

[Use transactions in a SQL pool in Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-transactions)

> SQL pool implements ACID transactions. The isolation level of the
> transactional support is default to READ UNCOMMITTED. You can change
> it to READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION by turning ON the
> READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option for a user SQL pool when
> connected to the master database.

You should bear in mind that the default transaction isolation level for dedicated SQL pools is `READ UNCOMMITTED` which does allow dirty reads.  So the way I think about it is, ACID (Atomic, Consistent, Isolated, Durable) is a standard and each provider implements the standard to different degrees through transaction isolation levels.  Each **transaction isolation level** can be strongly meeting ACID or weakly meeting ACID.  Here is my summary for `READ UNCOMMITTED`:

- **A** - you should reasonably expect your transaction to be atomic but you should (IMHO) write your code to be re-runnable
- **C** - you should reasonably expect your transaction to be consistent but bear in mind dedicated SQL pools does not support foreign keys and the NOT ENFORCED keyword is applied to unique indexes on creation.
- **I** - `READ UNCOMMITED` does **not** meet 'I' Isolated criteria of ACID, allowing dirty reads (uncommitted data) but the gain is concurrency.  You can change the default to `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` as described above, but you would need a good reason to do so and conduct extensive tests on your application as the impacts on behaviour, performance, concurrency etc
- **D** - you should reasonably expect your transaction to be durable

So the answer to your question is, depending on your transaction isolation level (bearing in mind the default is `READ UNCOMMITTED` in a dedicated SQL pool), each transaction meets ACID to a degree, most notably Isolation (I) is not fully met.  You have the opportunity to change this by altering the default transaction
at the cost of reducing concurrency and the now obligatory regression test.  I think you are most interested in **A**tomicity and my advice is there, make sure your code is re-runnable anyway.

You tend to see the 'higher' transaction isolation levels (`READ SERIALIZABLE`) in more OLTP systems rather than MPP systems like Synapse, the cost being concurrency.  You want your bank withdrawal to work right?

Answer (score 1):

It has guaranteed ACID transaction behavior.

Refer: [What is Delta Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-what-is-delta-lake), where it states:

> Azure Synapse Analytics is compatible with Linux Foundation Delta
> Lake. Delta Lake is an open-source storage layer that brings ACID
> (atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability) transactions to
> Apache Spark and big data workloads. This is fully managed using
> Apache Spark APIs available in Azure Synapse.

Comment: Does this really answer the question?  It seems specific to Delta Lake, which is not mentioned in the OP's post.